# WPF DataGrid horizontal cell selection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have to implement a WPF DataGrid with which it is possible to select only cells in one row. How could I achieve this? I know the properties `SelectionUnit` and `SelectionMode` but each combination of these two properties did not lead to success.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DPGridCR}" HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionUnit="Cell"
    SelectionMode="Extended" CanUserResizeRows="False" />
```

At this moment I am just able to select many cells in many rows or just select one single cell or select a whole row. But I want to select many cells in ONE row.

**Edit:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DesignerPro.Controls.DZLeerformularGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    x:Name="DZLeerformularGridControl">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ViewModel:DZLeerformularGridViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DPGridCR}" HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionUnit="Cell"
        SelectionMode="Extended" CanUserResizeRows="False">

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedCellsChanged">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" MethodName="DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

With the `EventTrigger` I tried to bind the `SelectedCellsChanged`-Event to my ViewModel. Your solution works fine in the code-behind but in my ViewModel it doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you using the CTRL key to do the multiple selection?

Comment: No. I just use the WPF default DataGrid with several `SelectionUnit` and `SelectionMode` combinations.

Comment: What I'm saying is, after you set SelectionUnit="Cell" and SelectionMode="Extended" it should work.  But, in order for the multi-select to happen, you need to hold CTRL while you click the cells.  (Or, you can click and drag, like Excel)  If you want it to operate differently, then you'll need to write some custom code.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in the way I like. I want to prevent that a user select cells in more than one row. The user is only allowed to select cells in ONE row. For example: The user select the cells three to seven in row eight. This is allowed but the user should not be able to select cells in row eight AND nine! Is there a smart way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this event handler to the SelectedCellsChanged event in the code-behind:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as DataGrid;

    if (grid == null || !grid.SelectedCells.Any())
        return;

    var row = grid.Items.IndexOf(grid.SelectedCells[0].Item);

    try
    {
        // Disable the event handler to prevent a stack overflow.
        grid.SelectedCellsChanged -= DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged;

        // If any of the selected cells don't match the row of the first selected cell,
        // undo the selection by removing the added cells and adding the removed cells.
        if (grid.SelectedCells.Any(c => grid.Items.IndexOf(c.Item) != row))
        {
            e.AddedCells.ToList().ForEach(c => grid.SelectedCells.Remove(c));
            e.RemovedCells.ToList().ForEach(c => grid.SelectedCells.Add(c));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Don't forget to re-enable the event handler.
        grid.SelectedCellsChanged += DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code produce some StackOverflowExceptions because this snippet create a recursive method. To disable the event handler doesn't prevent a stack overflow. How could I solve this?

Comment: I have tried to implement a lock-unlock-solution but that was not the right way :)

Comment: When the methods `Remove(c)` or `Add(c)` are called then the `SelectedCellsChanged` event will be fired. Due to this a recursion is created and leads to an stack overflow.

Comment: There is something else going on in your app. I've recreated this in a basic wpf app and have no stack overflow exceptions.  As long as you remove the event handler before and add it back in afterward, it shouldn't get called during the Remove() and Add().  Are you adding multiple event handlers by chance?

Comment: @PatrickVogt, can you post some more of the code?  Or, if you like, I can send you the wpf app that I created to test it.

Comment: I have edited my question. Now there are the whole XAML-File. Your solution works fine in code-behind but in my ViewModel it doesn't work :(